# Include reveal.js presentation in publish process

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I have the following folder structure:

- `~/org/notes/x.org` with notes in org files
- `~/org/presentations/y.org` with reveal.js presentations in org files
- `~/org/img/demo.png` with static images used in notes and presentations

I now want to publish all of them to `~/public_html/`. My spacemacs config contains the following configuration, which does not work:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(
      ("org-presentations"
       :base-directory "~/org/presentations"
       :base-extension "org"
       :publishing-directory "~/public_html/presentations"
       :recursive t
       :auto-sitemap t
       :publishing-function org-reveal-export-to-html
       :with-sub-superscript nil
       :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
       :auto-preamble t)

      ("org-notes"
       :base-directory "~/org/notes"
       :base-extension "org"
       :publishing-directory "~/public_html/notes"
       :recursive t
       :auto-sitemap t
       :publishing-function org-twbs-publish-to-html
       ;;:publishing-function org-publish
       :with-sub-superscript nil
       :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
       :auto-preamble t)

      ("org-static"
       :base-directory "~/org/img/"
       :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
       :publishing-directory "~/public_html/img/"
       :recursive t
       :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)

      ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-presentations" "org-static"))))
```

The presentations don't get published. Any idea for the correct publishing-function for reveal.js presentations?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about the same thing. 
I think the issue is that org-reveal-export-to-html is not a defined publishing function. 
There is a nice solution provided by Matt Price and it works on my system as well.
Here it is:
Define a publishing function that connects reveal to org-publish.

```
(defun mwp-org-reveal-publish-to-html (plist filename pub-dir)
  "Publish an org file to reveal.js HTML Presentation.
FILENAME is the filename of the Org file to be published.  PLIST
is the property list for the given project.  PUB-DIR is the
publishing directory. Returns output file name."
  (let ( (org-reveal-root "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/                         )
         (org-reveal-extra-css "css/theme/pikestreet.css"))

    (org-publish-org-to 'reveal filename ".html" plist pub-dir))
  )
```

After you define this function, you can use

```
("reveal"
       :base-directory "your directory"
       :base-extension "org"
       :publishing-directory " your directory"
       :publishing-function mwp-org-reveal-publish-to-html
       :section-numbers nil
       :recursive t
       :with-toc t
       )
```

It works like a magic!
Credit goes to: 
 https://matt.hackinghistory.ca/2015/07/11/creating-and-publishing-presentations-with-org-reveal/

Comment: Please summarize the solution you link to. This answer risks being deleted, because it is currently a link-only answer.